# Как умножить нечетные числа в массиве

Tags: java, циклы

1. Что необходимо добавить в код, что бы на выходе нечетные числа умножались на `n` число ?
2. Почему при замене `(int i : arr)`  на аналогичный `(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` выдает неправильный результат ?

```java
public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i : arr) if (i % 2 != 0) s.append(i +",");
    s.deleteCharAt(s.length()-1);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)  - в этом случае в i попадает индекс, а не значение, поэтому условие if (i % 2 != 0) надо заменит на if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) , а что касается умножение на n, принимайте в аргументы метода n и дописывайте к существующему условию else, в теле которого производите умножение

Comment: Странно, но при замене на  if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) результат выдает некорректный... Например при вызове метода с массивом {2,4,5,7,9,12} результат 2,3,4

Comment: если это так то 3 ка откуда?

Comment: так оно вам индексы пишет.. s.append(arr[i] + ","); - тут тоже само собой надо исправить)

Comment: Да. Вы правы. Невнимательно посмотрел. Только начинаю изучение ЯП )
А можете кусок кода написать, где именно переменную n с умножением после условия if вставлять. А то по неопытности не могу понять, ругается... Заранее благодарю.

Comment: после условного оператора добавляете else arr[i] = arr[i]*n; , а в сигнатуре метода добавляеете пермнную n printOddNumbers(int[] arr, int n)

Answer (score 0):

Переписал ваш код на стримах, немного изменил условие для наглядности. Надеюсь, ответил на интересующие вопросы:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 19};
        int multiplier = 2;

        printOddNumbers(arr, multiplier);
    }

    public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr, int multiplier) {
        // Обход индексов элементов массива
        IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            // Индексы элементов массива начинаются с 0
            // поэтому нечетные элементы имеют четные индексы
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            // По индексу берем элемент массива
            // и умножаем его на заданное число
            .map(i -> arr[i] * multiplier)
            // Выводим результат
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
┌-----------------┬------------------┐
│  Без метода map │    С методом map │
│ выводим индексы │ выводим элементы │
├-----------------┼------------------┤
│               0 │                2 │
│               2 │               12 │
│               4 │               16 │
│               6 │               38 │
└-----------------┴------------------┘
```

---

Если нужно точно как в задаче:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 19};
        int multiplier = 2;

        printOddNumbers(arr, multiplier);
    }

    public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr, int multiplier) {
        // Обход элементов массива
        Arrays.stream(arr)
            // Отбираем элементы
            // с нечетными значениями
            .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
            // Умножаем на заданное число
            .map(i -> i * multiplier)
            // Выводим результат
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
┌----------------┬----------------┐
│ Без метода map │  С методом map │
├----------------┼----------------┤
│              1 │              2 │
│              3 │              6 │
│             19 │             38 │
└----------------┴----------------┘
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавить доп параметр и в коде умножать:

   ```
    public static void printOddNumbers(int[] arr, int n) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : arr) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                s.append(i * n).append(",");
            }
        }
        s.deleteCharAt(s.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
   ```
2. Потому что надо работать не с i, а с элементом массива arr[i]:

   ```
    public static void printOddNumbers2(int[] arr, int n) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
                s.append(arr[i] * n).append(",");
            }
        }
        s.deleteCharAt(s.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
   ```